# RichTextBox not printing newline

Tags: c#, formatting, richtextbox

I have this method that replaces(in bold) some words in a string and show the changed string in a ritchtextBox.
In the final string I need to replace the @ symbol by a newline. 
I already tried  checked this forum tying several solutions, but nothing worked.

The method I use is

```
private string bold(string ing)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    ing = " " + ing + " ";

    builder.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
    foreach (string word in splitwords)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<![\w])" + word + @"(?![\w])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        ing = regex.Replace(ing, m => @"\b" + m.ToString() + @"\c0");
    }

    ing = ing.Replace(@"\b", @"\b ");
    ing = ing.Replace(@"\c0", @" \b0");
    ing = ing.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);

    builder.Append(ing);
    builder.Append(@"}");
     MessageBox.Show("builder.ToString():" + builder.ToString());
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

When I call the this method and "put it" in the ritchTextBox it doesn´t print the new line

```
ingred.Rtf = bold(ingd);
```

How should I solve this??

EDIT:: input string - line1 @ line2 @ line3

output in the MessageBox

```
Builder.ToString() : {\rtf1\ansi\b line1\b0
line2
line3
}
```

output in the ritchTextBox: line1 line2 line3

Comment: I am not seeing any `(\r)\n` in here O_O

Comment: As it is a RitchTextBoxI´m using  Environment.NewLine. But I already tried that, no joy

Comment: Ah I see it now. Does the `string` before doing the `Replace` contain any `@`?

Comment: yes, it does contain

Comment: Show us an example of the input string and it's output.

Comment: Also as others stated. Is `MultiLine` enabled?

Comment: Multiline is set to true. Edit question to show input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 ing = ing.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
```

Try

```
    ing = ing.Replace("@", @"\par\r\n");
```

Comment: \par is for paragraph so it's work like a hack here.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `Environment.NewLine` for adding new line also Make sure `yourRTB.MultiLine` property is set to true. assign string to richtext box like this  `yourRTB.AppendText(t)`

Comment: assign string to your textbox by setting its Rtf property I try this its working fine for me.

Comment: But it not What I´m doing in this line ? ingred.Rtf = bold(ingd);

Comment: assigning string using yourRTB.AppendText(t); work fine and add new line in richtextbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code For Repalce

```
 int startIndex = 0, index;
RichTextBox myRtb = new RichTextBox(); // if have A richtextBox Remove thisline and Use your Richtextbox
            myRtb.Rtf = STRRTF;// if have A richtextBox Remove thisline and Use your Richtextbox
     while ((index = myRtb.Text.IndexOf("@", startIndex)) != -1)
                {
                    myRtb.Select(index, word.Length);

                    myRtb.SelectedText ="\n";

                    startIndex = index + 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with a `"\r\n"` character sequence?

edit: is `MultiLine` property of `ritchtextBox` enabled?

Comment: It was one of the things I sqw in this forum and it didn´t work either